# date format in MS access insert is incorrect

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a problem with date format.

My computer's regional setting is "MM-dd-yyyy".

I have C# application. and i want user to enter date in "dd/mm/yyyy" format only.

when user enter 30/10/2010 (means 30th oct 2010) , access is not changing anything. it is ok.

but, if user enters 05/10/2010 (means 05th oct 2010) then on the lost focus of date text box, it automatically changes as 10/05/2010. it should remain as 05/10/2010.

can anybody tell me what is the solution?

Plz note, i don't want to change the regional setting.

Comment: where do you enter the date? If in msaccess form, have you tried to use input mask?

Comment: no in c# application

Comment: Reviewhttp://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: when use this code in c#  @"\#" +last.ToString(@"mm\/dd\/yyyy\") +"#" show this error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will have to parse the input using your forced format to obtain the correct datetime value.

Then format this to a neutral string expression to concatenate with your SQL statement:

```
string textDate = "05/10/2017";

IFormatProvider provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(textDate, "dd/MM/yyyy",provider);

string sql = "... #" + date.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# ...";
```

Will return:

```
date: 2017-10-05 00:00:00
sql : ... #2017/10/05# ...
```